# how to solve "when python script is running in background, the time.sleep() performs very bad?"

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm using wxpython and threading module of python to build a simple timer with GUI. I used time.slee(0.5) to measure the time. The problem is: Once I start the timer and switch to other program like chrome. Some times later when I switched back, the time displayed on my timer is very inaccurate. For example, if I set 3 minutes to run, it turns out that my timer is 3 times slower than the operating system clock.

After searching, I know that time.sleep() is unreliable, but it seems the gap is so huge that makes me doubt if there is something wrong.

I also noticed that If I don't put the script into background, then there is only 2-3 seconds difference.

I can accept several seconds difference, but not 2 "minutes".How can I solve it?

Comment: You might find that checking the current time and comparing it to a predetermined time might be more accurate.

Comment: If the Sleep() time is that unreliable, your box is grossly overloaded or your design is grossly bad:(

Comment: Because most modern desktop/server operating systems have pre-emptive schedulers you'll find that ``time.sleep()`` is not guaranteed to be very accurate; especially with other competing resources on the system.

Comment: to avoid drift, synchronize the sleeps with a system clock. You should probably use GUI-specific timer instead e.g., [`widget.after()` in tkinter or `GObject.timeout_add()` in Gtk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279).  See [code examples in the links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528935/timing-issues-in-metronome-script-in-python-using-pygame#comment45378176_28528935).

Answer (score 3):

sleep() does not guarantee scheduling after the time given. It just guarantees to sleep *at least* this time. It can very well sleep longer, depending on system load.

Just compare against the system time from time.time (or time.clock, depends on OS - read the notes in the documentation). after wakeup and use sleep() just not to occupy the CPU all time.

**Edit:**

There are several ways to improve that:
 - If your timer has just to wakeup after the time elapsed, you could simply sleep() until short before wakeup and busy-wait for the time completely elapse. That would block the GUI/app during the timeout. Not so good.

- You can use threading with one thread for display update at ca. 1s (or whatever you think appropriate) and another thread for the timeout as shown above. A bit complicated.

  - A third approach would to use sleep() for GUI-update without busy-wait for each second. That would give a bitt less accurate display, but less CPU performance. Short before the time elapsed, you could busy wait for the time remaining.

Ok, that much for voluntary consulting.

Comment: I tried to combine time.sleep() with "busy waiting" and even pure busy waiting. Both of them will lead to a 20-25% cpu usage Once I start the timer. Is there any way to improve its performance?

Comment: @Zumars: The better (and correct) way might be to use threading. But the accuracy is still not much better - for the same reasons as for sleep(). Actually, that would do the same call. Hmm... I edited my answer, my good deed today.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem by using event.wait() and multiprocessing module with good resolution and low cpu usage.